# A QMap esque container that allows for duplicate keys and preserves their insertion order

Tags: c++, qt

I have a UI with dynamically created Custom widgets.
Each custom widget has 2 QLineEdits from which user input has to be parsed.

Information from a each one of these Custom Widgets through its 2 QLineEdits has to be read and processed within my application.
Each CustomWidget directs one specific action of a machine for a determined period of time, so I'm trying to get a "todo list" for my machine like so:

```
MachineActionA : {param1, param2}
MachineActionD : {param1, param2}
MachineActionC : {param1, param2}
MachineActionA : {param1, param2}
MachineActionD : {param1, param2}
```

where param1 and param 2 are read from the QLineEdits

What I thought this would call for is a

```
QMap<QString, QPair<QString, QString>> map;
```

but quickly was reminded, that this does not allow for multiple (identical keys) to be inserted while preserving the previous value. In the example above the value of the first "MachineActionA" was overwritten by the one inserted between actions "C" and "D"
So I tried a QMultiMap approach:

```
QMultiMap<QString, QPair<QString, QString>> multi_map;
```

This fixes the key-overwrite issue but doesn't preserve the order of the inserted keys

I am sure this can be fixed through a rather trivial change of container and doesn't necessitate the custom data structure/iterator implementations or additional index-vectors/lists I have seen people post here.

Currently this rather cumbersome fix works for me

```
QVector<QPair<QString, QPair<QString, QString>>> complicated_pair_vector
```

but it isn't pretty.

**Is there a way I can create a map-esque container type that preserves the order of the elements added while also allowing for duplicate keys ?**

Edit: Wrote QMap twice, forgot to add the second QPair to vector

Comment: You could use `std::multimap`?

Comment: @ypnos I'm sorry I didn't include the QMultiMap specifier. Similarly std::multimap does not preserve the order of elements added if they have the same key.

Comment: Is your goal to have faster-than-O(n) lookup and insertion times?  If not, then your `QVector` solution seems to work pretty well, perhaps just make it a private implementation detail of your own container class, create a pretty public API for the rest of your code to call it with, and then use that.

Comment: Jeremy, since I work with a few dozen instructions to be read at most, the lookup and insertion speeds are not that relevant. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Why don't you use a `QMap<Key, QVector<Value>>` or `std::map<Key, std::vector<Value>`, then you control the ordering in the vectors per-key. Btw. I misunderstood your order-preserving requirement, I thought it was about ordering of keys Theoretically, you could mimic the ordering behavior also by using std::pair<Key, CreationIndex> as a key to a map, if you don't find it awkward. You would then have to work with std::map::lower_bound/upper_bound to find elements. Still efficient but pretty shitty code to maintain.

Comment: Ypnos: It is about preserving the order of the keys while having multiple keys. Sorry if that was a bit unclear.
@Jeremy Friesner
if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it as the solution.
Thank you !

Comment: I started writing an "OrderedHash" class and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369075/is-there-a-map-like-tool-in-qt-that-can-be-iterated-over-inserted-index/70436449#70436449.  It could modified fairly easily to support duplicate keys, i.e. making it a QMultiHash derivative instead of a QHash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your goal to have faster-than-O(n) lookup and insertion times? If not, then your QVector solution seems to work pretty well, perhaps just make it a private implementation detail of your own container class, create a pretty public API for the rest of your code to call it with, and then use that.